# Почему execl выходит из процесса?

Tags: c++, linux

Форкаю процесс, в нём запускаю с помощью execl другую программу. Делаю это в цикле:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    while(1) {
        execl(...);
    }
}
```

Казалось бы после завершения выполнения execl() цикл должен заново запустить execl(), но не тут то было. Просто завершается форкнутый процесс. Если выполняю через system(), то всё работает нормально, но нужно через execl().

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Ну так execl заменяет же ваш процесс.

Comment: А зачем? Странно...

Comment: Ну как бы by design

Comment: Если вам нужно запустить новый процесс, вам нужна комбинация fork/exec. Или spawn, если он доступен.

Comment: @sitev_ru: Пережитки древности по сути. Такой уж у exec смысл.

Answer (score 2):

Если не вдаваться в теоретические подробности, то Вам нужно сделать так.

```
pid_t pid;
for(;;){
  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){
     execl(...);
  }
}
```

И теория

> fork создает процесс-потомок, который отличается от родительского
>   только значениями PID (идентификатор процесса) и PPID (идентификатор
>   родительского процесса)

Функция fork только создает процесс

> Семейство функций exec заменяет текущий образ процесса новым образом
>   процесса.

а функции exec заполняют его.

Поэтому их используют всегда вместе.

Comment: Возможно автору вопроса нужен цикл с ожиданием выполнения второго процесса, а здесь они будут бесконечно стартовать без ожидания завершения предыдущего.

Comment: `используют всегда вместе`. [Не всегда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1653415/3240681), но часто.