# Дочерний процесс fork

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Начал разбираться с функцией `os.fork()` в Python. В процессе гугления понял, что это стандартная функция в Linux для создания дочерних процессов. Как её использовать в терминале у себя на Ubuntu не понял. Внятного примера применения в Python тоже не нашел. Обычно это `pid = os.fork()`, а дальше какая-то магия.

Что при этом происходит?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24538619/4827341

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548569

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Что при этом происходит?

Создаётся полная КОПИЯ процесса, выполнившего вызов fork(). С точки зрения ОС они различаются только тем, что первый процесс был запущен Вами (допустим - из консоли), а второй - вашей программой, вызвавшей fork. Соответственно, у них всё абсолютно одинаковое. За исключением ppid - id родительского процесса. Первый будет иметь ppid==pid  Вашего shell, а второй - pid этого процесса.

Соответственно, для того, что бы эти два ОДИНАКОВЫХ процесса могли работать далее по разному, ОС возвращает через fork() pid созданного процесса.

Для родителя это будет реальный pid процесса, который он создал.
Для дочернего - ноль, так как он ничего не создавал.

Отсюда следует, что сразу после вызова fork(), нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО использовать конструкцию вида:

```
if (pid > 0 ) {
    // Делаем что-то в родителе
} else if (pid == 0) {
    // Делаем что-то в дочернем
} else {
    // Обрабатываем ошибку
}
```